# Gridview not showing data (when I run the program, the form is blank)

Tags: c#

Please help me resolve this issue. For some reasons, I am not able to display a table from my database in gridview. Whenever I run the program, the windows form is blank (nothing all).

Connection Manager class starts here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OCUTutoringSchedule
{
    public class OCUTutoringScheduleDBConn
    {
        public static SqlConnection getStringConn()
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=  (LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="
                                  + "C:\\Users\\Honopac\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\"
                                  + "Projects\\OCUTutoringSchedule\\OCUTutoringSchedule\\"
                                  + "TutoringSchedule.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        return connection;
    }
}
```

}

Data Access Class starts here:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OCUTutoringSchedule
{
public class TutorDB
{
    public TutorDB()
    {

    }

    public DataTable displayTutor()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("TutorsInformation");

        string selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
        SqlConnection connString = OCUTutoringScheduleDBConn.getStringConn();
        connString.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);          
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

}

Form load event starts here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OCUTutoringSchedule
{
public partial class Tutoring_Schedule_Maintainace : Form
{
    public Tutoring_Schedule_Maintainace()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Tutoring_Schedule_Maintainace_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        TutorDB tutorDB = new TutorDB();

        DataGridView gv = new DataGridView();
        gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        gv.DataSource = tutorDB.displayTutor();
        gv.Visible = true;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `gv.Visible` to `true`, you need to add `gv` to the [Form.Controls Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `this.Controls.Add(gv);`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding your datagridview to your form. You can easily do that using the designer instead of instantiating it yourself.

```
gv.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 55)
gv.Size() = New System.Drawing.Size(130, 95)
this.Controls.Add (gv)
```

Comment: Also while you debug ensure DataTable contains some data, else grid will be anyway empty

Comment: Tarik, What did you mean when you said that I did not add gridview to my form? Can you give me an examle? I know how to use drag and drop windows controls, but I want to learn how to do it programmatically. Thank in advance for your help.